# Subsequent ajax calls with delay

Tags: jquery, ajax, setinterval

```
var F = function() {
    $.ajax({
        .
        .
        .
    })
    .done(function() {
        console.log('Hey, I am done');
        setInterval(F, 10000);
    });
}
```

So I wanna update some stuff every 10 seconds. The problem is that everytime the ajax call is done calls itself double times. So the output is:

```
Hey, I am done //First call (without delay)

// After 10 seconds
Hey, I am done

// After 20 seconds
Hey, I am done
Hey, I am done

// After 30 seconds
Hey, I am done
Hey, I am done
Hey, I am done
Hey, I am done
```

And goes on...
I am clearly missing something here! Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: You should use `setTimeout` in `.done()` or `setInterval(F)` outside of the callback.

Comment: Oh, thank you all, i can only "accept" one answer so I "accept" the first one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use interval, use timeout:

```
setTimeout(F, 10000);
```

BTW, you should call it on complete, not success:

```
 .always(function() {
        setTimeout(F, 10000);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have an interval that is creating a queue of requests to F that increases by 1 each time. Try setTimeout instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just add on extra line of Code

```
    done(function() {
            console.log('Hey, I am done');
            clearInterval(F); // clear the interval F
            setInterval(F, 10000); //reset the interval F
        });
```